# Change link on button with input from two dropdowns?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a button with a link that needs to change based on what the user selects from two dropdown menus.

I found this brilliant solution with one dropdown menu in here:

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('basic_plan');
sel.onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("abc").href = this.value + ".html";
}
```

```html
    <div class="dropdown-plans">
    <select id="basic_plan" name="bill_cycle">
        <option value="tri">3 Years - Rs. 100/month</option>
        <option value="bi">2 Years - Rs. 200/month</option>
        <option value="ann">1 Year - Rs. 100/month</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="button-plans">
<a id="abc" href="something"> Order now </a>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MHh46/1/

However I need a solution where the output link is based on two dropdown menus. For example:

```html
<div class="dropdown-plans">
    <select id="basic_plan" name="bill_cycle">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-plans2">
    <select id="basic_plan2" name="bill_cycle2">
        <option value="A">A</option>
        <option value="B">B</option>
        <option value="C">C</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="button-plans">
<a id="abc" href="something"> Order now </a>
</div>
```

But how would the Javascript part look in order for this to work?

For example if you select option "1" from dropdown #1 and option "A" from dropdown #2 the button links to www.link1.com, if you select "2" and "A" it links to www.link2.com, 3A = www.link3.com, 1B = www.link4.com and etc.

I hope my question makes sense.

Kind regards. :-)

Comment: Have you tried modifying the code to do what you desire?

Comment: While this sounds like an XY problem, I would suggest turning this into an actual form, but using the GET method for submission. That way your selections will be appended in a query string, and you can handle them in the receiving page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the drop downs so they both have the same class (class="dropdown-plans") and then you can tie a change event to both.  When either is selected, the event will trigger, and combine the value of both selections, and then assign the result to the href.

JQuery

```
$('.dropdown-plans').change(function() {
    var val = $('#basic_plan').val() + $('#basic_plan2').val();
    $('#abc').prop('href',val);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/errypkpc/)

**UPDATE**

[Here is an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/errypkpc/1/) showing how to assign a link based on the selectiosn made from the drop downs.  With this approach, you will need to define the mapping between the various combinations possible with the dropdowns and the related link that should be assigned.  I have only shown 2 combinations in the demo.

Comment: It's unclear if jQuery is available though as the question isn't tagged with that tag nor uses it in existing javascript code.

Comment: jQuery can be used. I've edited the question because the part about what link it needs to output was a bit vague. Apologies!

Comment: Thanks for the update. This did exactly what I required. Regards!

Answer (score 1):

```
var sel = document.getElementById('basic_plan');
var sel2 = document.getElementById('basic_plan2');
if(sel.value){
sel2.onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("abc").href = sel.value+""+this.value + ".html";
}}
```

This part works only if the first -select- is set. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Register an event handler that handles a change of any of your two dropdowns and gets the value of the selected options.

```
var sel = document.getElementById('basic_plan1');
var sel2 = document.getElementById('basic_plan2');

sel.onchange = dropdownChange;
sel2.onchange = dropdownChange;

function dropdownChange() {
    var fd = document.getElementById("basic_plan1");
    var sd = document.getElementById("basic_plan2");

    var firstValue = fd.options[fd.selectedIndex].value;
    var secondValue = sd.options[sd.selectedIndex].value;

    document.getElementById("abc").href = firstValue + secondValue + ".html";
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avqpt2nt/).

Comment: Hi Daniel,

First of all, thanks a lot for your great answer - to you and everybody. I do now realize that was unclear about one part and that I have made a mistake in my description of the issue.

When for example you select 1 + B the output does not necessarily have to be 1 and B put together.

Perhaps a situation can occur when 1+A = www.link1.com, 1+B = www.link2.com, 1+C = www.link3.com, 2+A = www.link4.com etc.

Does that make sense?

Apologies for the mistake, I only realized it after the answers was posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can add change event to both selects, and build the url after any change

```js
  var basic_plan = document.getElementById("basic_plan");
    var basic_plan2 = document.getElementById("basic_plan2");
    function changeUrl() {
      document.getElementById("def").innerHTML = "www.site.com/" + basic_plan.value + basic_plan2.value;
    }
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-plans">
    <select id="basic_plan" name="bill_cycle" onchange="changeUrl()">
        <option value="tri">3 Years - Rs. 100/month</option>
        <option value="bi">2 Years - Rs. 200/month</option>
        <option value="ann">1 Year - Rs. 100/month</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-plans2">
<select id="basic_plan2" name="bill_cycle2" onchange="changeUrl()">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
</div>
   <div class="button-plans">
   <a id="abc" href="something"> Order now </a>
   <br/>
   <span id="def"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see my code below or this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/HoangTran/8xtqpsye/) for reference:

```js
function GotoLink() {
  var sel = $('.basic_plan option:selected').text();
  var sel2 = $('.basic_plan2 option:selected').text();
  alert('www.site.com/' + sel + '' + sel2 + '');
  document.getElementById("abc").href = 'www.site.com/' + sel + '' + sel2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-plans">
  <select id="basic_plan" class="basic_plan" name="bill_cycle">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-plans2">
  <select id="basic_plan2" class="basic_plan2" name="bill_cycle2">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="button-plans">
  <a id="abc" href="#" onclick='GotoLink()'> Order now </a>
</div>
```